# Very slow shutdown/reboot when running without sudo

Tags: systemd, shutdown, pop-os

I am experiencing very slow system shutdowns/reboots if I use the corresponding buttons that the OS provides for this and when executing shutdown/reboot commands as my user. It takes up to ~3 minutes.

If I execute the command on the command line there is a long delay before anything visible happens. When running the same command again, it shows that there is already a shutdown in progress. After about 30-60 seconds the screen turns black, then it takes another 30-60 seconds before the shutdown/reboot has been processed.

**Strangely enough, everything works fine if I issue the shutdown/reboot command via sudo**

I have spent the last 3 days - performing over 100 system reboots - debugging this and trying out many different things but nothing seems to work.

It appears that I have found the corresponding info in the log regarding the second delay:

> systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices - timed
> out, issuing SIGKILL to PID 11498.

While I am still not sure what's causing this, I would like to focus on the first delay first because the second delay does not always occur but the first one does. Unfortunately I cannot find anything that would lead me to the cause of the first delay. The syslog looks like this:

```
Aug 16 19:47:02 dbus-daemon[3449]: [session uid=1000 pid=3449] Activating service name='org.kde.Shutdown' requested by ':1.85' (uid=1000 pid=10955 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/ksmserver-logout")
Aug 16 19:47:02 dbus-daemon[3449]: [session uid=1000 pid=3449] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.Shutdown'
Aug 16 19:47:02 dbus-daemon[3449]: [session uid=1000 pid=3449] Activating service name='org.kde.kdeconnect' requested by ':1.22' (uid=1000 pid=4734 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell ")
Aug 16 19:47:03 dbus-daemon[3449]: [session uid=1000 pid=3449] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.kdeconnect'
Aug 16 19:47:03 org.kde.kdeconnect[10984]: kdeconnect.core: Could not query capabilities from notifications server
Aug 16 19:47:12 org.kde.kdeconnect[10984]: ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 10984, errno = 2
Aug 16 19:47:12 systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 sddm[1586]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Aug 16 19:47:43 at-spi-bus-launcher[5462]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Aug 16 19:47:43 sddm[1586]: Auth: sddm-helper crashed (exit code 15)
Aug 16 19:47:43 sddm[1586]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Aug 16 19:47:43 sddm[1586]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 15
Aug 16 19:47:43 sddm[1586]: Socket server stopping...
Aug 16 19:47:43 sddm[1586]: Socket server stopped.
Aug 16 19:47:43 sddm[1586]: Display server stopping...
Aug 16 19:47:43 xdg-desktop-por[5395]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk: Fatal IO error 11 (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar) on X server :0.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopping Session 5 of user michael.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Removed slice system-getty.slice.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Removed slice system-modprobe.slice.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Block Device Preparation for /dev/mapper/cryptdata.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Containers.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: e2scrub_all.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: fstrim.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Discard unused blocks once a week.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.kde[5508]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Aug 16 19:47:43 org.kde.KScreen[5073]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Aug 16 19:47:43 kglobalaccel5[4427]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: logrotate.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily rotation of log files.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: man-db.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily man-db regeneration.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: motd-news.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Clean PHP session files every 30 mins.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: ua-messaging.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Ubuntu Advantage update messaging.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: update-notifier-motd.timer: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopped Check to see whether there is a new version of Ubuntu available.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: lvm2-lvmpolld.socket: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 kactivitymanagerd[4951]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Closed LVM2 poll daemon socket.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.socket: Succeeded.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[3397]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[3397]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Aug 16 19:47:43 ModemManager[1319]: <info>  caught signal, shutting down...
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopping Modem Manager...
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
Aug 16 19:47:43 NetworkManager[1130]: <info>  [1629136063.0371] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Aug 16 19:47:43 ModemManager[1319]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Aug 16 19:47:43 systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
```

Operating system is Pop!_OS 21.04.

I would highly appreciate any help in resolving this.