# Change command executed by click on shutdown/reboot buttons

Tags: kde, shutdown, reboot, pop-os

I am having the issue that the system is taking forever to shutdown/reboot (or won't do it at all).

The issue can be avoided if the following commands are used for shutdown/reboot:

`sudo reboot` / `sudo shutdown`

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening for days now without success.

Is there a way to change the command that a click on the corresponding buttons (shutdown / reboot) executes? If they can be changed to execute the command as described above, it would get rid of the issue.

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665114/very-slow-shutdown-reboot-when-running-without-sudo This question runs contrary to your previous statement: *There is obviously a permission related issue going on because it works just fine when running the shutdown/reboot command via sudo. So I would really like to resolve this the proper way.* Running via `sudo` is trying to solve the issue without properly investigating it.

Comment: I'm not sure about reboot but shutdown can be changed in `/etc/acpi/actions/power.sh` in Fedora. No idea what your distro is and how it works. ACPI daemon which handles the shutdown button could be set up differently in different distros.

Comment: That's not contrary. The suggestion that has been made was to set a timeout of 10 seconds, after which all services would be killed. That is a recipe for data loss. Running via sudo does however shutdown the system properly. That's a huge difference. I would obviously prefer to find the actual cause of this issue but I have been on this issue for 5 days now and quite frankly have no patience left for this anymore.

Comment: The OS is Pop!_OS 21.04, based on Ubuntu 21.04. There is no /etc/acpi/actions directory.

Comment: If I were you I'd start with filing a bug report against systemd. `reboot` and `shutdown` must have the same behaviour regardless of how they were started (via `sudo` or directly). https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues

Comment: Can you confirm that both `readlink -f $(which reboot) $(which shutdown)` returns two lines with `/usr/bin/systemctl`? I am clutching at straws here.

Comment: I believe that the shutdown / reboot buttons do not even execute "shutdown" or "reboot".  I changed the symlink for those command to a script that executes "sudo reboot" / "sudo shutdown". After that executing "reboot" / "shutdown" worked but using the corresponding buttons still did not. They seem to use this: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.login1.html

Comment: @terdon Yes, they are both symlinks to /usr/bin/systemctl. But see my above command too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised. I admit that I have always used `shutdown` from a terminal since I always have one open and it's faster than moving my hand to the mouse. But I know I'm a bit of an edge case. One possible solution would be to create a `.desktop` file and have that execute `sudo shutdown`, and then configure sudoers to allow passwordless execution of that command. That should let you have something to click that shuts down properly. Would that be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: I already did that, but to be honest this is REALLY bugging me.. I decided to move from Windows to Linux due to the many problems and privacy issues. The fact that not even the shutdown / reboot buttons can be used now is extremely frustrating. I was therefore hoping that there is at least a way to modify the command that a click on those is executing..

Comment: You could always try a different desktop environment. KDE is just one among many.

Comment: I tried other ones too, KDE is definitely the one I would like to stay with

Comment: Maybe you could use more mainline distros, btw. No one knows or can vouch for if PopOS! respects your privacy. After all only a few thousand people use it.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/hc1oex/cant_change_power_button_action/fvdkmfb?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) may help. Bascially, it should show you "who" is handling the power button.